# display images from mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

my controller is

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class pickoftheday_display extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        //$this->load->library('upload');
        //$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('pickoftheday_display_model','',TRUE);
        $this->pickoftheday_display_model->get_pickoftheday_image();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function index()
    {
                $this->load->view('pickoftheday_display');


    }

    public function get_pickoftheday_image()
    {
        $data['get_pick_picture']=$this->pickoftheday_display_model->get_pickoftheday_image();
    }
}
```

model is

```
class pickoftheday_display_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->helper('security');
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }

    public function get_pickoftheday_image()
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pick_of_the_day order by id desc ");
        if($query->num_rows>0)
        {
            return $query->result();

        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

view code is

```
    $val=array();
    $link=array();
    var_dump($get_pick_picture);
    foreach($get_pick_picture as $key)
    {
        $val[]= $key->image;
        $link[]= $key->link;
    }
echo $link[0]
```

how to display image in view..

Comment: what is the output you are getting now?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: get_pick_picture

Filename: views/pickoftheday_display.php

Comment: `echo '<img src="'.base_url($link[0]).'" />;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You did not pass data to view file.
2. You didn't set data to pass to view file.

In index function, you have to call

```
public function index()
{
    $data['pick_picture']=$this->pickoftheday_model->get_pickoftheday_image();
    $this->load->view('pickoftheday_display',$data);
}
```